# Deploying Activiti on JBoss 7 AS

Tags: jboss7.x, activiti, deploying

I am just a "beginner" in JBoss, but was asked to deploy Activiti into it. After "googling" and reading the forum of Activiti I've understood that it is rather difficult but not impossible. I've found [this post](http://www.mastertheboss.com/activiti-bpmn/activiti-bpmn-on-jboss-as-7/page-2), made everything like written there, got the error about CDI, but I don't understand what should I do with the archive from [Daniel Meyer's blog](https://bitbucket.org/meyerd/activiti-cdi-jbossas7.1.1-setup/src)

Answer (score 0):

You can use it as a skeleton/example for a project using Activiti engine.

Just checkout the code, change to one of `programmatic` or `spring` and `mvn war`. Then deploy `target/<some>.war` in AS7 and look at the console log for messages. You should see something like "Process engine ... is up and running!".